# Configuraciones de correos. Laravel

Tags: laravel, email, hosting

Tengo un hosting compartido en hostinger.  Mi problema con este es que no he logrado configurar la salida de mailings desde laravel. Las configuraciones que da el hosting son las siguientes.

```
Host SMTP                 smtp.hostinger.mx
Puertos SMTP (seguro)     587
```

Las configuraciones que tengo en mi .env son las siguientes:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.hostinger.mx
MAIL_PORT=993 
MAIL_USERNAME=correo@example.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tsl
```

Corro en la linea de comandos el

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Y cuando hago una prueba de envió me sale el siguiente error.

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.hostinger.mx 
>       [Unable to find the socket transport "tsl" - did you forget to enable it
>        when you configured PHP? #153217872]

Comment: el valor para `MAIL_ENCRYPTION` es **tls** y  no `tsl` , además debe verificar el número del puerto de su configuración ya que no concuerdan.

Comment: Ya intente poniendo tls en minúsculas y mayúsculas, he intente en todos los puertos de salida que tiene el hosting.  Igual intente con SSL y STARTTLS

Comment: si haces cambios en el archivo `.env` tienes que "limpiar el cache": `php artisan cache:clear` y te recomiendo que no caches cuando estés en fase de desarrollo